# Is PUT broken by default in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a new ASP.NET MVC project, updated NuGet packages (to `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />`
) and added a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Put | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public string Index()
    {
        return "bombaclat";
    }
}
```

I ran it on IIS Express and found out that PUT returns 404 from IIS StaticFile handler (both GET and POST works just fine).

I can fix it either by allowing all verbs for `ExtensionlessUrlHandler`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Or by running `UrlRoutingModule` for every request:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

(and so, setting RAMMFAR to true will work as well)

1. Is it by design that I need to mess with Web.config to make PUT
   work?
2. Are the solutions equivalent? If no, what are the differences, and how should I decide which one to use?
3. Is there a reason PUT is disabled for `ExtensionlessUrlHandler` by default?

(just in case: I'm on Windows 8.1 Enterprise, VS 2013, IIS 8).

---

UPD: If you tick `WebApi` when creating the project, VS will add the `ExtensionlessUrlHandler` config part. So, I guess it's safe to use it

Comment: PUT and DELETE are sometimes considered as "unsafe" (due to the fact that the user "could" alter the file system -- I'm no expert, you should do some research on that...); therefore, these verbs are, by default, deactivated on some servers.

Comment: There is also the issue with WebDav module, which wants to handle Put and Delete itself, so it could cause clashes, historically, normal websites didn't use put and delete, so in my mind, MS just disabled them in IIS to make life easier for the bulk of web dav developers.  I'd enable it on the extensionless url handler as that is what powers the mvc routing etc, and then remove the web dav module if you have listed to prevent clashes

Comment: @AndreiV thanks for the info, but I couldn't find anything about PUT and DELETE being insecure, and for that matter, any reasoning behind them being disabled by default for the handler.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen other mentions of security, but the issue I myself and other colleagues have run into (usually once per person :)) is the WebDAV issue mentioned by Slicksim

You could try this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
<!--all the other webserver stuff -->
</system.webServer>
```

I suppose you could also remove WebDAV completely from your IIS, but I think the above is enough.